# Avoiding Copyright infringment

Tags: html, flash, copyright-display

How can I add popular flash or html games to my website without the possibility of having copyright infringement problems? I have researched and came up with the possibility of emailing all the creators of these content, but seeing how it is such a large sum of them, I believe it to be impractical to do such a thing. That why I wanted to know whether there was a more efficient way to post html games created by others without infringing on their copyrights. 
.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you will need to do is give the author or creator credit, beginning with the copyright symbol. Here is an example:

**This (game title or source title) © Copyright 2017, Joe Schmoe, (professional title goes here)**

That statement gives the creator credit for their work. I have read in some places that extra steps like emailing the copyright offices is recommended but not mandatory. The most important thing to understand is no matter what if their game is already copyrighted by them, you must ask for their permission(I know you stated that it would be impractical to do so but it is still mandatory). As long as you give them credit in the long run you should be fine. If you are looking for more specifics, research copyright infringement laws and regulations just to be safe. Hope this helps.